# I added a reference to the main project, but the testing project still doesn't see the classes of main

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

My solution has a project that contains all the program logic.
I created a unit test project, added a reference to the main project, but still can't use classes from it to create tests.

My code:

```
namespace Program
{
    public class Class
    {
        public Class()
        {
        ///
        }

        public int foo()
        {
        ///
        }
    }
}
```

My tests code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Program; // cs0246

namespace ProgramTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ClassTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void foo_()
        {
            // Arrange
            Class testClass; // this code also have cs0246 error
            // Act

            // Assert
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, `using Program;` underlined in red with cs0246 error. But namespace ProgramTests have the reference to Program (there is a checkmark in the reference manager). How can i fix it?

**Image of Solution Explorer**
[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of your Solution explorer with open `Dependencies` & `Projects` so I can see closes what's going on there? Thanks

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LcYWVdM

Comment: What do those warmings say?

Comment: I'm so sorry about this question, the problem was in test sample. I created MStest on net framework 4.8, but my program using .NET 6.0. Thanks for helping  anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check the framework version you are using. Maybe Tests library has framework which is no compatible with ClassLib Framework

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the problem.  Thanks